# QWS OpsWorks "Permission Denied (publickey)", when trying to login to instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, aws-opsworks

I have 2 instances in OpsWorks.
The first I can login fine using ssh.
The second, if I add an EBS volume, and mount it somewhere like "/mnt/data", or anywhere else, when I try to login I get:

```
"Permission Denied (publickey)"
```

to ssh I use:

```
"ssh -v ubuntu@10.0.2.184"
```

This is the full log:

```
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OpenSSL 1.0.1k-fips 8 Jan 2015
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 50: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 10.0.2.184 [10.0.2.184] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA de:82:9f:df:1a:a6:b3:59:11:c5:93:f9:95:57:d4:49
debug1: Host '10.0.2.184' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/ec2-user/.ssh/known_hosts:48
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: imported-openssh-key
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: imported-openssh-key
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: imported-openssh-key
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

If I don't mount the EBS volume, then it logs in just fine.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If it's an Amazon Linux EC2 instance then you should be logging in as the *ec2-user* user, not as the *ubuntu* user. So, ssh -v ec2-user@10.0.2.184.

Comment: It isn't an Amazon EC2 instance, it is an Ubuntu instance. As I said in the post I can login OK as long as I don't assign an extra EBS volume to the instance. I can use "ssh ubuntu@10.0.2.184" if the EBS volume is not assigned.

Comment: I cannot think of a reason why the mounted EBS volume could cause this. I would double check that I'm actually connecting to the correct EC2 instance (using the wrong ip/dns name is a common mistake), that the instance was launched with the correct keypair, and I'm connecting with the correct private key. Also I would explicitly provide the -i xxx.pem option with ssh. Note that I had mentioned ec2-user earlier because you seem to be SSHing from an Amazon Linux instance (the debug logs show /home/ec2-user) so I just wanted to rule out a simple mistake.

Comment: Correct I am SSHing from a NAT instance within my VPC. I know I don't know why it would be affected by the the EBS Volume being assigned or not; I mean literaly if I stop the instance, then remove the volume, and then restart it ( same instance ), and use the same ssh command from the prompt history on the NAT instance, then it logs in; in other words nothing else changes other than the EBS volume not being attached.

Comment: Can you review the SSH logs on the machine? Also, maybe compare the console output (Actions | Instance Settings | Get System Log) in the two situations and see if there's anything unusual at startup when you have the EBS volume mounted?